# When does a deep learning approach perform better than a hidden Markov model in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language

I want to apply deep learning approaches to NLP, I am wondering if Deep learning is better than Hidden Markov models? Both have hidden layers, except that NN works on weights and HMM works on probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is a little odd, HMMs as the name suggests encode a specific set of modeling assumptions, while deep learning is an umbrella term used to describe learning a series of non-linear transformations of the input data.

It is possible to come up with a bad deep learning based model for a simple NLP task like part of speech tagging which does worse than an HMM. But with a reasonable model (e.g. a RNN based pos tagger) deep learning almost always does better.

A key advantage of deep is that it uses/learns distributed representations (e.g.a word is represented by an "embedding") while graphical models (like HMM) typically do not.

Like many other fields, deep learning based methods are now state-of-the-art in many NLP tasks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "A key advantage of deep is that it uses/learns distributed representations (e.g.a word is represented by an "embedding") while graphical models (like HMM) typically do not." or point to where can one read more about that?